# New javascript file is not loaded to browser in development

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I just started to create new javascript functionality for my site so I created a new file for it. I wrote some basic alerts and bindings to the file and reloaded my browser so that I would see it in action. But nothing happened.

I tried Firebug to see if my new javascript file is loaded, and it seems that it is not.

I then tried to add my javascript file to the application.js file require section so that it should be loaded. But with no luck. I have `//= require_tree .` in there also, so the new javascript file should have been loaded already because of that.

I tried to do a small change to one of my other javascript files and noticed that those changed files are delivered to the browser.

Now I'm puzzled. What is keeping my new javascript file from getting to my browser?

Comment: does deleting `tmp` and restarting the server help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment, delete `tmp` in the project directory and restart the server by `rails s`.